# Python Pandas Pivot tables to pie chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

What is the best way to change all the non zero values in the following pivot table into a pie chart using percentages of the total(sum of all the data in the pivot table)?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'axis1': ['Unix','Window','Apple','Linux'],
                 'A': [3,0,1,10],
                 'B': [1,0,0,0],
                 'C': [0,30,0,20],
                 'D': [1,0,12,0],
                 }).set_index(['axis1'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         A  B   C   D
axis1                
Unix     3  1   0   1
Window   0  0  30   0
Apple    1  0   0  12
Linux   10  0  20   0

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

So basically I want to create a pie chart from the pivot table where values are present and use labels such as 'Unix A' with a value of 3/sum=% of everything in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot pie charts with matplotlib (eg see http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/pie_demo.html).

First stack your data (so the different columns become an index level, see [stack docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack)), and then select only the positive ones:

```
In [13]: s = df.stack()

In [14]: s = s[s>0]

In [15]: s
Out[15]: 
axis1    
Unix    A     3
        B     1
        D     1
Window  C    30
Apple   A     1
        D    12
Linux   A    10
        C    20
dtype: int64
```

Then you can plot this with matplotlib `pie` (for the labels, I paste the two levels of the index together in a list comprehension):

```
In [16]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ...: ax.pie(s, labels=["{0} {1}".format(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in s.index], 
    ...:        autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

leading to this output:
[image]